# Download the file 'sending file with download name'

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, rxjs

I have an Angular 6 application and I want to download a generated PDF from my .NET Core API.

Each of the calls seems to be valid, but I'm not sure how to download/open the file.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.FileContentResultExecutor:Information:
>   Executing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult, sending file
>   with download name 'test.pdf' ...

The `Reporting` API:

```
public IActionResult CreateReport()
{
  XtraReport report = m_ReportingManager.GetReport();

  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  report.ExportToPdf(ms);

  HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  FileContentResult result = new FileContentResult(ms.GetBuffer(), "application/pdf")
  {
    FileDownloadName = "test.pdf"
  };

  return result;
}
```

And in my Angular component I have 2 calls to a service (1 from SO and 1 one did myself)

```
public getReport1() {
    this._reportViewerService.getReport()
      .subscribe(blob => {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "test.pdf";
        link.click();
      }, error => { console.log(error) });
  }

  public getReport2() {   
    this._reportViewerService.getReport().subscribe(
      (result: any) => window.open("http://localhost:44302/Reporting/test.pdf", "_blank"),
      (error: any) => this._loggerService.logError(error),
      () => this.loading = false
    );
  }
```

And my service looks like this:

```
  public getReport(definitionKey: string, reportParameters: ReportParameter[]): Observable<any> {
    const parameters = {
      key: definitionKey,
      reportParameters: reportParameters
    };

    return this._http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + 'CreateReport', parameters);
  }
```

Comment: @Hypernate You are missing `{ responseType: 'blob' }` from your `this._http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + 'CreateReport', parameters);` it should be `this._http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + 'CreateReport', parameters,{ responseType: 'blob' });`

Comment: I can see in my Reponse-Header that the file "test.pdf" is included, now what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the File Saver package to handle the file download.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

I did it like this in my app, hopefully you can adapt it to yours:

```
downloadFile(data: Response){
  let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  let url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  console.log(url);
  window.open(url);
}

getPdf() {
   const options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders,
        observe?: 'body',
        params?: HttpParams,
        reportProgress?: boolean,
        responseType: 'blob',
        withCredentials?: boolean
    } = {
        headers: null,
        params: null,
        responseType: 'blob'
    };

this.http.get(`your api endpoint`, options)
  .subscribe(blob => {
    saveAs(blob, 'file.pdf');
  });
 }
```